# downloading a file which frequently changes url path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am just curious what would you do if you have to download a file which changes url path every fortnight ? The file url link is a dataset(excel sheet) provided by a third party website.. so I have no control over it. and it doesn't have any pattern I know. I  cannot use webclient in the code as it changes the url frequently. I want to download that to my local machine. I am a newbie.. so excuse if I am not making a point clear..

Comment: Where are you trying to download the file? Download to your server from another host? Download to the browser from your server? Who controls the file path? Does the name change have a pattern? How do you get the new value of the url each time?

Comment: I will edit the question..

Comment: name change doesn't have a pattern the file path is controlled by third p[arty. it is downloaded from another server to my host. The new url is set by the website which delivers the information. so ... I have no control over it...

Comment: You might store the url in a database table then your code queries this field whenever you need it. You'll need another mechanism to keep this updated. If this website publishes an api you can automate this.

Comment: Theres no api thats the problem.....

Comment: Since the url changes every now and then I can't use the url.. again. How can I store the new url every fortnight..?

Comment: How do you know when it changes and what is the new path? Can you answer that in a deterministic way? Did that website intend for users to automatically download this file? If it's downloading to your machine why can't your browser handle the task?

Comment: Then you can mine (scrape) the original page for the link. Examine the html and see if the page has static values you can identify.

Comment: I will have a look how to do it. Thanks for the help though..

Comment: Think of it like this, you obviously can manually determine the current URL of these files right? So how are you manually determining the URL? That will then determine the options you have available for a program doing the same.

Comment: Yeah, true  understood...

Answer (score 0):

As long as you store the currently valid url in `some_variable` you can use that in whatever part of your code calls the download url. If it is derived from some method then you would need to run the method to get the new url.

Perhaps if you showed us your existing code we could help more.

Comment: thanks for the reply...To make it a bit clear. It is a  website which provides the data in the datasets. instead of api. so the dataset files which are excel  sheets ( downloading URL links are changed frequently)... let me know if thAT didn't make sense.....